# help needed to resize an image in php

Tags: php, image, resize, thumbnails

I have a bit of code that generates thumbnails from an uploaded image. The only problem is that it cuts portrait images off, rather than resizing the portrait image to fit the height of the thumbnail, landscape images are fine. I was wondering if anyone could help me out to change the code so it will place portrait images inside the thumbnail properly? (if that makes sense?)

Here's the code:

```
$setSize        = 150;
$setHSize       = 113;
$jpeg_quality   = 75;

list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($origPath);

$newW = $setSize;
$newH = round( $height * ( $setSize / $width ) );

$img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($origPath) or notfound();
$dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $setSize, $setHSize );
$heightOffset = round( ($setHSize-$newH)/2 );

$white = imagecolorallocate($dst_r, 255, 255, 255);
imagefilledrectangle($dst_r, 0, 0, $setSize, $setHSize, $white);
imagecopyresampled($dst_r, $img_r, 0, $heightOffset, 0, 0, $newW, $newH, $width, $height);

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($dst_r, $thbPath, $jpeg_quality);
```

I just don't fully understand the way php creates images, so any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: How are $setSize and $setHSize calculated? That's missing in your code, and that is where the problem is.

Comment: Sorry, they're manually set, I've edited the code to include those :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you compute $newW and $newH is incorrect for what you want. You are giving preference to the width, so most landscape images will look okay, but portrait will be cut off. Try the following instead:

```
// assume landscape and see how things look
$newW = $setSize;
$newH = round( $height * ( $setSize / $width ) );
if ($newH > $setHSize) {
    // portrait image
    $newH = $setHSize;
    $newW = round( $width * ( $setHSize / $height ) );
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps.

```
<?php 
define('DOCROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);  
include_once(DOCROOT."/dbc.php");
```

//****************************************| Resize based on height

```
$photo_height = 350;
```

//****************************************| Get the file from the post

```
$file = $_FILES['file'];
$path_thumbs = (DOCROOT."/gallery/"); 
$path_big = (DOCROOT."/trash/");
```

//****************************************| Check permission

```
if (!is_writeable($path_thumbs)){
   die ("Error: The directory <b>($path_thumbs)</b> is NOT writable");
}
if (!is_writeable($path_big)){
    die ("Error: The directory <b>($path_big)</b> is NOT writable");
}
```

//****************************************| Make sure you have a file

```
 if (isset($file)){

   $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
   $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
   $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
   $file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

   $getExt = explode ('.', $file_name);
   $file_ext = $getExt[count($getExt)-1];
```

//****************************************| Make new name

```
   $rand_name = md5(time());
   $rand_name= rand(0,999999999);
```

//****************************************| See the kind of file we have

```
if($file_size){
  if($file_type == "image/pjpeg" || $file_type == "image/jpeg"){
  $new_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($file_tmp);
  }
  elseif($file_type == "image/x-png" || $file_type == "image/png"){
  $new_img = imagecreatefrompng($file_tmp);
  }
  elseif($file_type == "image/gif"){
  $new_img = imagecreatefromgif($file_tmp);
  }
```

//****************************************| Get the height and width

```
  list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file_tmp);
       $imgratio=$height/$width;

 if ($photo_height >= $height){
 //*********** Dont resize if the image is smaller then $photo_height = 350;
 $newwidth = $width;
 $newheight = $height;
 }
 elseif ($imgratio>1){
 $newheight = $photo_height;
 $newwidth = $photo_height/$imgratio;
 }
 else{
 $newwidth = $photo_height;
 $newheight = $photo_height*$imgratio;
 }

 if (function_exists(imagecreatetruecolor)){ $resized_img = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight); }
else{ die("Error: Please make sure you have GD library ver 2+");
}

imagecopyresampled($resized_img, $new_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

ImageJpeg ($resized_img,"$path_thumbs/$rand_name.$file_ext",'100');
ImageDestroy ($resized_img);
ImageDestroy ($new_img);
}
move_uploaded_file ($file_tmp, "$path_big/$rand_name.$file_ext");
$newimage = "$rand_name.$file_ext";
}
else { 
echo "Sorry, there was a problem, Please try again.\n\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> adaptiveResizeImage

or

> adaptiveCropThumblanil

in Imagick can help you